# How can I setup custom license for my github repository?

Tags: licensing, github

During creation of new Github repository I could choose license under which my project will be hosted on Github. I didn't do that because Github suggested only few licenses to choose (and WTFPL wasn't on the list). However, after repository was created I cannot find any option to indicate either WTFPL license or any other.

Is it possible to setup license for my repo after it was created on GitHub?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely. Create a new file called `LICENSE` and [put your terms in there](http://www.wtfpl.net/txt/copying/). For quick adding of the license you can use [addalicense.com](http://www.addalicense.com/) or manually push the file to GitHub using various tools. *(or [quickly via the GUI](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-new-files/))*

<sub>*License file names are normally; `LICENSE`, `LICENSE.txt`, `LICENSE.md`*</sub>

Comment: site down......

Comment: GitHub now does pretty much the same thing as addalicense did: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-license-to-a-repository/

Comment: My question is how to choose the license option in Github's own pull-down menu?  Would it create a legal conflict?

Answer (score -2):

Just go here: https://choosealicense.com and choose what license you want.

There are 3:

1. **I need to work in a community.**
   *want everything will be open source and anyone can claim that's theirs.*
2. **I want it simple and permissive.**
   *This will give you the apache license [ This will give close source your code with this ]  BUT choose this for professional purpose only and you care about your work and want your code should not be stolen choose option  3.*
3. **I care about sharing improvements.**
   *This says I will fork this and I modify this but you have to open source it anything you make out of it legally, If anyone fork's your code and you have this license on your repo that person has to open source their code by law.*

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The question clearly asks how to set WTFPL license.

Comment: I have mentioned the link right and I explain the different licenses in brief. So that's that!